Synthetic Tests Terraform and Datadog
Does anyone know how to configure Datadog Synthetic Tests with Terraform via API? I'm having trouble finding content online that explains this.
I tried following the documentation and also a few tutorials, but they are outdated.

Is this what you're looking for? https://registry.terraform.io/providers/DataDog/datadog/latest/docs/resources/synthetics_test
